# Passing Google API key to Leaflet Control Geocoder?

Tags: leaflet, geocoding

I'm using [Leaflet Control Geocoder](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder) to implement Google search, I am trying to pass my API key from Google Geocoder

```
        let googleGeoCoderProvider = L.Control.Geocoder.google('MYGOOGLEAPIKEY');

    L.Control.geocoder({
        geocoder: googleGeoCoderProvider,
    }).addTo(map);
```

but the results in the console are
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=undefined&address=trompillo

is processing API key as undefined, the same problem with `L.Control.Geocoder.Google('MYGOOGLEAPIKEY');`

for it to work, I had to open the plugin code and directly replace `key:` with my APIKEY

```
    var Google = /*#__PURE__*/function () {
  function Google(options) {
    this.options = {
      serviceUrl: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json'
    };
    L__namespace.Util.setOptions(this, options);
  }

  var _proto = Google.prototype;

  _proto.geocode = function geocode(query, cb, context) {
    var params = geocodingParams(this.options, {
      key: 'MYAPIKEY',
      address: query
    });
```

how can I pass the API key from my JS code?

Comment: Have you paid for the subscription? As far as I am concerned Google has a few API keys. Check you use the right one.

Comment: @MKR it is correct, because if I put my API key directly in the plugin code, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
    let googleGeoCoderProvider = L.Control.Geocoder.google({
        apiKey: 'MIGOOGLEGEOCODERAPIKEY',
    });
```